# Frustrating App Crash

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Having previously had my application working *perfectly*, it now continually crashes now that I have attempted to add extra, but almost identical functionally. By extra functionality I mean Edit Texts, Spinners, etc.  This is hugely frustrating, as it clearly is something very small that seems to be the issue.

My `LogCat` is showing that there is an error on Line 114 of my Property class, however, I can't understand why this would be an issue as it did not affect the application before added functionality was implemented.

**LogCat**

```
    02-26 21:19:20.424 9478-9478/com.example.benchalmers.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.benchalmers.myapplication, PID: 9478
                                                                                     com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.example.benchalmers.myapplication.Property does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zze(Unknown Source:51)
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzb(Unknown Source:772)
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zza(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                         at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
                                                                                         at com.example.benchalmers.myapplication.PropertyActivity$4.onDataChange(PropertyActivity.java:114)
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source:13)
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source:65)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
02-26 21:19:20.425 9478-9478/com.example.benchalmers.myapplication E/UncaughtException: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.example.benchalmers.myapplication.Property does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zze(Unknown Source:51)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzb(Unknown Source:772)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zza(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
                                                                                            at com.example.benchalmers.myapplication.PropertyActivity$4.onDataChange(PropertyActivity.java:114)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source:13)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source:65)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Previous to making these changes, I was able to add, update and delete records perfectly, with no hiccups whatsoever. This is what leads me to believe that the issues I'm having are easily fixed.

At the moment the screen loads up for 1 second and then it crashes almost immediately.

I have made small changes to variable names etc. thinking that that might help, but to no avail.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.  I'm very new at Android, and with Stack! First Post!

**PropertyActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.benchalmers.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PropertyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String PROPERTY_NAME = "propertyname";
    public static final String PROPERTY_ID = "propertyid";

    EditText editTextProperty;
    EditText editTextPostcode;
    EditText editTextBedrooms;
    EditText editTextBathrooms;
    Button buttonAddProperty;
    Spinner spinnerFuel;
    Spinner spinnerStatus;
    Spinner spinnerEPC;

    DatabaseReference databaseProperties;

    ListView listViewProperties;

    List<Property> propertyList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_property);

        databaseProperties = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("properties");

        editTextProperty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProperty);
        editTextPostcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPostcode);
        editTextBedrooms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBedrooms);
        editTextBathrooms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBathrooms);
        buttonAddProperty = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddProperty);
        spinnerStatus = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerStatus);
        spinnerEPC = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerEPC);
        spinnerFuel = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerFuel);

        listViewProperties = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewProperties);

        propertyList = new ArrayList<>();

        buttonAddProperty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                addProperty();

            }
        });

        listViewProperties.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                Property property = propertyList.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddTenantsActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(PROPERTY_ID, property.getPropertyId());
                intent.putExtra(PROPERTY_NAME, property.getPropertyAddress());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        listViewProperties.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Property property = propertyList.get(position);

                showUpdateDialog(property.getPropertyId(), property.getPropertyAddress(), property.getPropertyPostcode(), property.getPropertyBedrooms(), property.getPropertyBathrooms(), property.getPropertyStatus(), property.getPropertyEPC(), property.getPropertyFuel());
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseProperties.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                propertyList.clear();

                for(DataSnapshot propertySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Property property = propertySnapshot.getValue(Property.class);

                    propertyList.add(property);

                }

                PropertyList adapter = new PropertyList (PropertyActivity.this, propertyList);
                listViewProperties.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void showUpdateDialog(final String id, String propertyAddress, String propertyPostcode, String propertyBedrooms, String propertyBathrooms, String propertyStatus, final String propertyId, String propertyName) {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_dialog, null);

        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText editTextName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        final Button buttonUpdate = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
        final Spinner spinnerFuel = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerFuel);
        final Button buttonDelete = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Updating Property " + propertyName);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
                String postcode = editTextPostcode.getText().toString().trim();
                String bedrooms = editTextBedrooms.getText().toString().trim();
                String bathrooms = editTextBathrooms.getText().toString().trim();
                String status = spinnerStatus.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String epc = spinnerEPC.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String fuel = spinnerFuel.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){

                    editTextName.setError("Name Required");
                    return;
                }

                updateProperty(propertyId, status, postcode, bedrooms, bathrooms, id, name, epc, fuel);

                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                deleteProperty(propertyId);
            }
        });

    }

    private void deleteProperty(String propertyId) {
        DatabaseReference drProperty = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("properties").child(propertyId);
        DatabaseReference drTenants = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tenants").child(propertyId);

        drProperty.removeValue();
        drTenants.removeValue();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Property has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    private boolean updateProperty(String propertyId, String status, String postcode, String bedrooms, String bathrooms, String id, String name, String epc, String fuel){

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("properties").child(id);
        Property property = new Property (id, name, postcode, bedrooms, bathrooms, status, epc, fuel);

        databaseReference.setValue(property);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Property Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;
    }

    private void addProperty(){

        String address = editTextProperty.getText().toString().trim();
        String postcode = editTextPostcode.getText().toString().trim();
        String bedrooms = editTextBedrooms.getText().toString().trim();
        String bathrooms = editTextBathrooms.getText().toString().trim();
        String status = spinnerStatus.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String epc = spinnerEPC.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String fuel = spinnerFuel.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(address)){

            String id = databaseProperties.push().getKey();

            Property property = new Property (id, address, postcode, bedrooms, bathrooms, status, epc, fuel);

            databaseProperties.child(id).setValue(property);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Property Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "You must enter a property", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

**Property.java**

```
package com.example.benchalmers.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by benchalmers on 21/02/2018.
 */

public class Property {

    String propertyId;
    String propertyAddress;
    String propertyPostcode;
    String propertyFuel;
    String propertyBedrooms;
    String propertyBathrooms;
    String propertyEPC;
    String propertyStatus;

    public Property(String id, String address, String postcode, String bedrooms, String bathrooms, String status, String epc, String fuel ) {

        this.propertyId = propertyId;
        this.propertyAddress = propertyAddress;
        this.propertyPostcode = postcode;
        this.propertyFuel = propertyFuel;
        this.propertyBedrooms = bedrooms;
        this.propertyBathrooms = bathrooms;
        this.propertyEPC = epc;
        this.propertyStatus = status;
    }

    public String getPropertyId() {
        return propertyId;
    }

    public String getPropertyAddress() {
        return propertyAddress;
    }

    public String getPropertyPostcode() {
        return propertyPostcode;
    }

    public String getPropertyFuel() {
        return propertyFuel;
    }

    public String getPropertyBedrooms() {
        return propertyBedrooms;
    }

    public String getPropertyBathrooms() {
        return propertyBathrooms;
    }

    public String getPropertyEPC() {
        return propertyEPC;
    }

    public String getPropertyStatus() {
        return propertyStatus;
    }
}
```

**PropertyList.java**

```
package com.example.benchalmers.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class PropertyList extends ArrayAdapter<Property> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<Property> propertyList;

    public PropertyList(Activity context, List<Property> propertyList) {

        super(context, R.layout.property_list_layout, propertyList);
        this.context = context;
        this.propertyList = propertyList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.property_list_layout, null, true);

        TextView textViewProperty = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewProperty);
        TextView textViewPostcode = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewPostcode);
        TextView textViewBedrooms = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewBedrooms);
        TextView textViewBathrooms = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewBathrooms);
        TextView textViewStatus = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewStatus);
        TextView textViewEPC = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewEPC);
        TextView textViewFuel = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewFuel);


        Property property = propertyList.get(position);

        textViewProperty.setText(property.getPropertyAddress());
        textViewPostcode.setText(property.getPropertyPostcode());
        textViewBedrooms.setText(property.getPropertyBedrooms());
        textViewBathrooms.setText(property.getPropertyBathrooms());
        textViewStatus.setText(property.getPropertyStatus());
        textViewEPC.setText(property.getPropertyEPC());
        textViewFuel.setText(property.getPropertyFuel());

        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase requires a no-argument constructor in your Property class so that you can use `getValue(Property.class)`. So add this constructor to your Property class:

```
public Property() {}
```